# Serializing objects that has non primitive data members

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class with the following structure

```
    public class MyClass:
{
    public GMapMarker marker; // from GMap.NET library
    public TwitterStatus tweet; // from TweetSharp library
    public List<MYTriple> triples = new List<MYTriple>();
    public List<MYGraph> Graph = new List<MYGraph>();
}
```

and I have the list

```
List<MyClass> mylist;
```

I just want to serialize/save the list into a file and load it again in the next start of my program,

the list might contains hundreds of results, I only care about the performance.

I tried Jason, I got an Exception when Deserializing the list

> InvalidOperationException Instances of abstract classes cannot be created

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: [`XMLSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) can serialize non-primitive members provided that they themselves are serializable.

Comment: the issue here that the non-primitive members are not from a serializable type, and I cannot edit them.

Comment: @AboudZakaria: Can you post an example of the class that you consider a "not serializable type"? _Why_ is the type _not_ serializable? EDIT: Without knowing why you consider your types to not be serializable we may be shooting in the dark as to what serializer is _capable_ of doing the work, let alone which one will provide the "fastest way to do that".

Comment: well, I tried Jason, I got an Exception when Deserializing the list, it says: InvalidOperationException Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I've edited my question, I meant 'performance' by saying the fastest way.

Comment: @AboudZakaria: Looks like there are derived and abstract classes which can be an issue for some serializers; can you post your _actual_ classes used? Regarding your performance requirement that it "might contain hundreds of results", this is relatively _very small_ especially when performed _once_ on program startup (I deserialize 22000 objects in 184 _milliseconds_ with `XmlSerializer`). Performance is likely a non-issue; focus on a serialization routine that is _simple_ and _maintainable_ (and take Marc Gravell's advice to heart: separate your serialization models from your 3rd party models)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different serialization options have different features and trade-offs. There is no one option that does everything you want, because:

- not everything is `[Serializable]` (for `BinaryFormatter`) - plus `BinaryFormatter` is virtually always a bad choice
- not everything has a public parameterless constructor suitable for `XmlSerializer`
- and so on, for every serializer you can name (and trust me, I can name plenty): they all have different features and things they can/can't do - usually with good protocol reasons, not just apathy / incompetence

IMO, the problem here is that you are trying to serialize implementation details rather than serializing data. If you create a custom DTO model that just represents the *data* (but which has no dependency on 3rd-party types) then it will be possible to create a sane serialization model that works very efficiently with your choice of serializer, and which doesn't break horribly when you upgrade a library reference, or switch to a different library completely.

Some serializers (protobuf-net does, certainly) allow you to mix and match by way of serialization surrogate types, meaning you can tell it to silently substitute some types when it encounters them (in particular, if 80% of your model is serialization-friendly, this lets you swap out the other 20% as part of the engine) - but without knowing more about the specifics here it is hard to say whether that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.net it most reliable using the code below

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mylist, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\mylist.json", json);
```

Comment: That really depends on whether the types in question work with json.net; there is absolutely no guarantee of this, especially when working with complex 3rd party library objects

Comment: Then you have to make less sophisticated object

Answer (score 0):

using json.net;

```
   File.WriteAllText(@".\temp.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myInstance));



  MyClass instanceOnLoad = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(File.ReadAllText(@".\temp.txt"));
```

Doesn't get much easier than that!

Comment: That really depends on whether the types in question work with json.net; there is absolutely no guarantee of this, especially when working with complex 3rd party library objects

Comment: @MarcGravell interesting, I haven't run into such a situation but most everything I use json.NET on is a proprietary type.